# flutter / Material3 / I don't know how to use the custom colors specified in the Material theme builder in the Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-ui

https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/custom-colors

I was looking into how to use Material3 in Flutter and was looking through the above page, but I can't find a specific way to use the "custom colors" described in the above page in Flutter.

Is there an explanation somewhere?

---

https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/#/custom

I was able to output key colors by using the material theme builder on the above page.

I tried to specify two "Custom colors" and clicked on the "Export" button (for Flutter) to output the file.
However, I could not find the specified custom colors in the output file.

Is this not yet supported by Flutter?

Comment: Related: https://m3.material.io/libraries/additional

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I'll stay up to date.

Comment: Material 3 does not use exact seed color. It converts to another color similar to the seed color.